# Inserting a chart made with imageCreat() php into HTML <td> cell

Tags: php, html, image, charts

My code is a bit complex for generating the image array but the general idea is to create 8 pie charts that then need to be displayed in a column of charts in a table. What am I doing wrong to get the images down in my html.  This function is located in the same file as the html.

building the images

```
$FileHandle = fopen($FileName, 'r') or die("can't open file!!");

//Getting total for each question
$i = 0;
$start = 0;
$finish = 0;

while (($row = fgetcsv($FileHandle, 1024, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $total[] = $row[0] + $row[1] + $row[2] + $row[3] + $row[4];
    $average[] = round(((1 * $row[0] + 2 * $row[1] + 3 * $row[2] + 4 * $row[3] + 5 * $row[4]) / $total[$i]), 2, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);

    $start = 0;
    $finish = 0;

    $myImage[$i] = ImageCreate(200, 200);

    $white = ImageColorAllocate($myImage[$i], 255, 255, 255);
    $red = ImageColorAllocate($myImage[$i], 255, 0, 0);
    $orange = ImageColorAllocate($myImage[$i], 191, 64, 0);
    $olive = ImageColorAllocate($myImage[$i], 128, 128, 0);
    $green = ImageColorAllocate($myImage[$i], 64, 191, 0);
    $lt_green = ImageColorAllocate($myImage[$i], 0, 255, 0);

    $finish = ($row[0] / $total[$i]) * 360;
    //echo $start . ' ' . $finish . '<br>';
    if ($finish != $start) {
    ImageFilledArc($myImage[$i], 100, 100, 50, 50, $start, $finish, $red, IMG_ARC_PIE);
    $start = $finish;
    $finish += ($row[1] / $total[$i]) * 360;
    }
else{
    $start = $finish;
        $finish += ($row[1] / $total[$i]) * 360;
}
    if ($finish != $start) {
        ImageFilledArc($myImage[$i], 100, 100, 50, 50, $start, $finish, $orange, IMG_ARC_PIE);
        $start = $finish;
        $finish += ($row[2] / $total[$i]) * 360;
    }
    else{
        $start = $finish;
        $finish += ($row[2] / $total[$i]) * 360;
    }
    if ($finish != $start) {
        ImageFilledArc($myImage[$i], 100, 100, 50, 50, $start, $finish, $olive, IMG_ARC_PIE);
        $start = $finish;
        $finish += ($row[3] / $total[$i]) * 360;
    }
    else{
        $start = $finish;
        $finish += ($row[3] / $total[$i]) * 360;
    }
    if ($finish != $start) {
        ImageFilledArc($myImage[$i], 100, 100, 50, 50, $start, $finish, $green, IMG_ARC_PIE);
        $start = $finish;
        $finish += ($row[4] / $total[$i]) * 360;
    }
    else{
        $start = $finish;
        $finish += ($row[4] / $total[$i]) * 360;
    }
    if ($finish != $start) {
        ImageFilledArc($myImage[$i], 100, 100, 50, 50, $start, $finish, $lt_green, IMG_ARC_PIE);
    }
    $i++;
}
```

and here is what i tried down in the html block

```
<td><?php echo $average[0] ?></td>
<td><?php imagepng($myImage[0]); ?></td>
<td><?php echo $total[0] ?></td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to use a separate file for the image generation and call it with

```
<img src = "chart.php">
```

Answer (score 0):

As a practical matter, your imagepng() function needs to have a header() that tells the browser that your script is sending a PNG file.  That doesn't work well if you intermix the PNG file into a browser output stream with the echo statements.  When I have done this I simply write the PNG files into a directory on the server and send a standard HTML  tag with the URL of the PNG files.  That is probably the easiest way to get the pie charts to your client.

Best regards, ~Ray

Comment: This is for an assignment in school so I saddly cannot do that, The instructions allow for only 3 files, one form, the php file, and the txt file to store the results of a survey.  I cannot write to any other files, this is what is giving me a hard time, all of the graphs must be generated in the result page.  Is it possible to generate the graphs in a script within the <td> tags?  I tried that earlier and it just over wrote everything.

Comment: I can use a separate script apparently to generate the charts, so using that in the <td> might work. I created a new file called chart.php and it is being called with `<img src = "chart.php">` with a header and the last line being `imagepng($myimage[0])` but I am still getting nothing